# Pass <input> value to Django view

Tags: python, django

Let's say I have the following pointless example view:

```
def foo(request, input):
    return HttpResponse()
```

and in a template I have a form:

```
<form method="get" action="{% url 'foo' ??? %}">
    <input id="myinput" type="text" name="myinput">

    ...

</form>
```

Finally, I have the following url in my URLconf:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^foo/(.+)/', views.foo, name='foo'),
]
```

What I would like to do, is pass the value entered by the user into the input with the id of `#myinput` to the `foo()` view function. To put it another way, you should be able to enter `bar` in the html input, and when you submit the form it will take you to `foo/bar/`.

I know that within the foo view I could access the value of the input easily with `request.GET['myinput']`, but I want it to show up in the url as well.

This seems like it should be a fairly common task, but I have not been able to come up with a solution yet. Any suggestions would be appreciated. My Frankenstein's Monster of a first Django site is almost complete, and this is one of last pieces I am missing.

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this? You'll have to define a view with a very general regex to forward them to, and that's going to preclude you putting virtually anything else under `foo/`.

Comment: You are right off course, but my actual url is quite different. I guess I simplified my example a little too much. It will really be something like `items/search/nameofitem` where `nameofitem` is the part I want passed to the view from the input.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve with this?

Comment: Is this supposed to be for searching?

Comment: It's very unusual to construct a URL like that, even in a REST interface. It's far more common to have something like `items/search/?search_query=nameofitem`

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist that makes sense. I am very new to Django and web development, and have just been hacking my way through, learning as I go. So maybe I need something like `action="{% url 'foo' %}?search_query=nameofitem"` as the form action in my template? But how do I pass `nameofitem`?

Comment: It would happen automatically if you just used `{% url 'foo' %}` with a GET action anyway.

Comment: Use what you have without `???` and change `name="myinput"` to `name="search_query"`. The rest will happen like magic :D

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist Thanks for your help! I got it working thanks to you talking me through it. I tried to explain how I was able to arrive at a solution. If you would like to summarize your advice in an answer, I would be happy to accept it.

Comment: @elethan I could do that but you've got a great answer in the body of your question. Take the portion from **UPDATE** downward and move it to an answer. You can accept your own. I'd rather upvote yours than make a crappy copy of it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## The source of my misunderstanding

Although I did not make this clear in an attempt to simplify my example and avoid using app-specific code, my use case is a simple search view. The view was actually one of the first views I wrote in the start of my Django journey, and I mistakenly was `POST`ing my data instead of `GET`ing it. This was making it so that if I was searching for the item `foo`, it would take me to the detail page for `foo`, but the url would be `mysite/search/` (i.e., the search query is not included in the url though it is included in the request), and I can't return to those search results by visiting the url `mysite/search/`.

While I was using a `GET` request in my toy example in this question, I didn't realize that I had been using a `POST` in my app, and that with some minor tweaking I can get the functionality I want for free very easily. I know that all of this is extremely obvious to veteran and even intermediate web developers, but for someone starting from scratch without web or cs experience, things like `HTTP` can be a little confusing. At least for me it is. Thanks so much to @Two-Bit Alchemist for explaining this in a way that I can understand.

## Applying all this to my toy example

I would get rid of the passed parameter in my view:

```
def foo(request):

    # If I want to do something with the search query, I can access it with
    # request.GET['search_query']

    return HttpResponse()
```

change my form in my template to:

```
<form method="get" action="{% url 'foo' %}">
    <input id="myinput" type="text" name="search_query">

    ...

</form>
```

and change my url to:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^foo/search/', views.foo, name='foo'),
]
```

As @Two-Bit Alchemist said: "The rest will happen like magic". If a user enters `bar` in the input and submits the form, they will be taken to `foo/search/?search_query=bar`. This is what I was looking for.